Fixed-effects interval-data regression model
xtintreg fits a random-effects regression model in which the dependent variable may be measured as point data, interval data, left-censored data, or right-censored data. Is there any command or way to fits the same type of model but with fixed-effects?
Or more simply imagining I have a two-year panel, how can I set up a first-difference model where the dependent variable is interval (may be measured as point data, interval data, left-censored data, or right-censored data)? In the latter case using intreg.
I could not find any useful information in this regard. I therefore thank anyone who would like to try and answer this question.
